# Resistor between vcc and control signal in a rpi controlled relay board

Tags: pcb-design, relay, raspberry-pi, optoelectronics

I have been researching to design a rpi controlled relay board and I found these two schematics from two companies. Personally I trust the company in the image above but I am confused about R3 (10k) and why they connect it to the control signal. What function does this resistance have? What happens when the control signal is HIGH? Would the circuit from above work? In the one below they don't use it, would it work too?

[image: 2 different diagrams]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I am confused about R3 (10k) and why they connect it to the control signal. What function does this resistance have?

R3 is a **pull-up resistor**. It prevents the signal input (IN1) to be floating. With R3, IN1 will be kept at logic-hi by default *(i.e. when the IN1 pin is not configured at the RPI side, or when the IN1 input is not connected physically)*. So, by default, the relay will not be triggered.

> What happens when the control signal is HIGH? Would the circuit from above work?

From Ohm's Law, no current will flow through R3 and the opto's LED. And thus the relay will not be triggered. If IN1 is driven low then the potential difference will lead a non-zero current to flow through both R3 (around 0.5mA) and the opto's LED, so the relay will be triggered. So yes, the circuit will work as expected.

> In the one below they don't use it, would it work too?

It can work, too. But if the IN1 input is not physically connected to the RPI side then the relay **may** get a false trigger when you touch the IN1 line by your hand. It appears that the below one trusts the RPI side to be always connected physically.

Comment: I would add that I **did** work with a board of the second kind. Besides requiring the pi to be plugged, it also needs the program driving the GPIO to be running (or stuck in the state you desire). Long term, floating signals have interesting consequences. I would suggest staying away from those products.

Comment: The pull-up resistor should not be needed, though, because no current will flow into a floating input, so the relay will not be activated.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. I hope this post will help others too.